# disable ie8 clip rect

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

So very simply. I used `clip : rect` in my css, but I DON'T want to use it for ie8. IE8 has its own stylesheet, but I can't figure out how to undo `clip:rect`. Any ideas?

What I've tried:

Normal style sheet

```
#thing{
    clip : rect(0 30px 255px 30px);
}
```

IE style sheet

```
#thing{
    clip : none;
    clip : rect(0 1000px 1000px 1000px);
}
```

Those two are all I can think of a neither makes it as if `clip:rect` was never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the right and bottom to the actual dimensions of the `absolute` element and the other two to zero. Assuming a 400px x 400px size, then...

```
clip: rect(0 400p 400px 0);
```

...sets the clip to the top left and bottom right corners, which is essentially no clip.

**Update** you also might try...

```
clip: auto;
```

...since that is apparently the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional-reveal comment to apply the `clip` style to all but IE8:

```
<!--[if !IE 8]>--><style>#thing {clip: rect(0 30px 255px 30px);}</style><!--<![endif]-->
```